# todonotes and tikzexternalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, todonotes

In my document I use `todonotes` and `TikZ`/`pgfplots`. After activating the externalization in `TikZ` I realized that `todonotes` are all exported as well (because they are based on `TikZ`).

This behaviour is inconvenient, it would be much better for me to tell `tikz-external` to ignore all `\todo`.

I know I can generally disable the externalization with `\tikzset{external/export=false}` and turn it on only for selected plots, but the inverse would be more convenient.

Comment: At the start of the document say `\tikzexternaldisable`, and then wrap the normal figures in `\tikzexternalenable {your tikz code} \tikzexternaldisable`. I haven't tested it, but that should be possible, no? Or wrap the todo macros in a personal macro using the reverse. I don't use `todonotes`, so I can't say how that would look.

Comment: @Psirus: I'm not experienced in TikZ, but wrapping the todo macro sounds better because you only have to do it once in the preamble and can easily change it later.

Comment: I agree. Now that I read it again, my first suggestion is already covered in the question...

Comment: Would `\newcommand{\xtodo}[1]{{\tikzexternaldisable\todo{#1}}}` or similar not do the trick?

Comment: @Martin It actually does, but I forces me to redefine `\missingfigure` and basically all the macros from `todonotes`. This is certainly possible but just a little inconvenient.  If you put this down as an answer anyway I will accept it as it answers the above question.

Comment: The documentation of the package now mentions the same solutions suggested here, namely `\newcommand{\ruggedtodo}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\todo[#1]{#2}\tikzexternalenable}`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I had this very problem a while ago, just for the `\todo` command (I never use `\missingfigure`). Here's how I fixed it (place this in your preamble, somewhere after `todonotes` and `tikz`/`pgfplots` is called):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\@todo[#1]{#2}\tikzexternalenable}
\makeatother
```

Now, `\todo` will be ignored by the externalization process.

Hence, for the `\missingfigure` command you need

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\missingfigure}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\@missingfigure[#1]{#2}\tikzexternalenable}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Your redefinition of the `\missingfigure` command does not work, as there is no `\@missingfigure` in the package. I am not sure though how to do it differently; trying to use `\let\oldmissingfigure\missingfigure` causes LaTeX to complain about TeX capacity being exceeded.

Comment: the replacement of \todo works fine, however for \missingfigure the solution provided by @rook (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115095/4419) works fine

Answer (score 14):

For me neither of the proposed solutions worked. Maybe it is platform-dependent, taking into consideration the significant number of up-votes in favor of the accepted answer.

However, mSSM's approach with `\let` was close. The reason for it not to work properly with `\missingfigure` is that the latter consumes an optional argument. The simple `\let` fails to copy all required information to a new macro. According to **[this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-patch)** piece, one should use the *letltxmacro* package. Eventually, my working version is:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro{\oldmissingfigure}{\missingfigure}
\renewcommand{\missingfigure}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\oldmissingfigure[{#1}]{#2}\tikzexternalenable}

\LetLtxMacro{\oldtodo}{\todo}
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\oldtodo[#1]{#2}\tikzexternalenable}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have played around with `\missingfigure`, but a simple `\renewcommand{\missingfigure}...` will not work, as given in the answer by @Frits.

The only solution I found was defining a new command:

```
\newcommand{\extmissingfigure}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\missingfigure[#1]{#2}\tikzexternalenable}
```

Working with `\let`, i.e.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\tikzexternalize

\let\oldmissingfigure\missingfigure
\renewcommand{\missingfigure}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\oldmissingfigure[#1]{#2}\tikzexternalenable}

\begin{document}

\missingfigure{Ah!}

\end{document}
```

unfortunately raises an error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
<to be read again> 
\tikzexternal@orig@tikzfadingfrompicture 
l.18 \missingfigure{Ah!}
```

Comment: Finally, I managed to overcome the issues you encountered. You may want to have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found another workaround which just modifies the original implementation of the `todo` command. Just modify

```
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{%
  % Add to todo list
  \addcontentsline{tdo}{todo}{\protect{#1}}%
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, baseline=-0.75ex]%
    \node [coordinate] (inText) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  %
  % Make the margin par
  \marginnote{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
      \definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
      \draw node[draw=black, fill=orange, text width = 3cm] (inNote)
      {#1};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
    \draw[draw = orange, thick]
      ([yshift=-0.2cm] inText)
      -| ([xshift=-0.2cm] inNote.west)
      -| (inNote.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  %
}%
```

by inserting `\tikzexternaldisable` before and `\tikzexternalenable` after the `tikzpicture` envoronment:

```
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{%
  \tikzexternaldisable
  % Add to todo list
  \addcontentsline{tdo}{todo}{\protect{#1}}%
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, baseline=-0.75ex]%
    \node [coordinate] (inText) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  %
  % Make the margin par
  \marginnote{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
      \definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
      \draw node[draw=black, fill=orange, text width = 3cm] (inNote)
      {#1};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
    \draw[draw = orange, thick]
      ([yshift=-0.2cm] inText)
      -| ([xshift=-0.2cm] inNote.west)
      -| (inNote.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \tikzexternalenable
  %
}%
```