# todonotes with tikzexternalize - white space problem

Tags: tikz-external, todonotes, white-space

For a larger document including many TikZ pictures I am using tikzexternalize and the todonotes package. Based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42486/todonotes-and-tikzexternalize) I (re-) defined a command that automatically excludes the todo notes from externalization, which works as expected. However, as my todo notes sometimes span multiple lines I started writing the notes in a seperate line (instead of *inline*) like this

```
Next line will be a todo.
\todo{todo goes here}
Text goes on...
```

Doing this gives me a really annoying double white space that I am trying to get rid of without changing thousands of lines in my LaTeX documents.

The following MWE points out the problem alongside how it looks when defining `\tikzexternaldisable` and `\tikzexternalenable` right around the `\todo{}`

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\usepackage{todonotes}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\todoo}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\@todo[#1]{#2}\tikzexternalenable}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
   \noindent
   Hello Hello\newline
   Hello
   \todoo{wrong spacing}
   Hello\newline  
   Hello
   \tikzexternaldisable\todo{proper spacing}\tikzexternalenable
   Hello\newline
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of MWE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I found a working solution by including `\ignorespaces` in the definition of the command:

```
\newcommand{\todoo}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\@todo[#1]{#2}\tikzexternalenable\ignorespaces}
```

This results in the desired behaviour

[image: desired behaviour]